# Условия с активностью jtextfield

Tags: java, swing

Есть два `jtextfield` и один `jbutton`.

`jtextfield` задаются параметры `setEnabled(true)` или `false` в зависимости от условий

при нажатии на `button` хочу чтобы считывал setEnabled с jtextfield, типо

```
if (jtextfield1.getEnabled(fasle)) {
  System.out...
} else if (jtextfield1.getEnabled(true)) {
   System.out...
} ...
```

Но метода `getEnabled` нету

Как организовать условия такое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Но метода `getEnabled` нету

Но есть метод [`isEnabled()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isEnabled()), который возвращает текущую доступность компонента.

Comment: Вообще, геттэры для булевских типов используют имена начинающиеся на is или has.